# wordpress custom field values through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i am working on a jquery slider that have thumbnails in the bottom and i want them to link with related videos. what i am doing for that is i am adding a post from admin, the title contain the title of image, the content area contain the thumbnail image and for the video link i am adding a custom field.

come to slider again if i am doing the same process for images only(not video) it work fine. i click on thumbnail in the bottom and large image displays in slider. i am getting the source of image that i am clicking through this line of code

```
   var url = $(this).attr("src");
```

it gives me the source of the image from img tag. every thing is fine. but now my exact point is that i want to get the custom field value through the above piece of code but i dont know how to do that as i tried so many methods randomly from the internet but nothing work fine for me.

hope you guys will understand what i am saying if not i will give further details with code if required.

any help will be grately appriciated.

here is my full code(php and html)

```
        </div>
        <div class="video-gallery">
            <a class="prev browse left"><<</a>
            <div class="scrollable" id="scrollable">
                <div class="items">
                    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
   <?php
  $thePosts = get_posts('numberposts=50&category=4');
  foreach($thePosts as $post) :
  setup_postdata($post);
  $custom_field = get_post_meta($post->ID,'video path', true);
  echo '<div class="myclass" style="display:none" id="'.$custom_field.'"></div>';
  the_content();?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php else : ?>
   No Results
  <?php endif; ?>
                </div> 
            </div>
```

here is the javascript jquery

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(".video-gallery img").click(function() {
// see if same thumb is being clicked
if ($(this).hasClass("active")) { return; }

// calclulate large image's URL based on the thumbnail URL (flickr specific)
var url = $('.myclass').attr('id');
alert(url);
// get handle to element that wraps the image and make it semi-transparent
var wrap = $(".image_wrap").fadeTo("medium", 0.5);

// the large image from www.flickr.com
var img = new Image();


// call this function after it's loaded
img.onload = function() {

    // make wrapper fully visible
    wrap.fadeTo("fast", 1);

    // change the image
    wrap.find("iframe").attr("src", url);

};

// begin loading the image from www.flickr.com
img.src = url;

// activate item
$(".video-gallery img").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");

  // when page loads simulate a "click" on the first image
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function to retrieve the desired custom field, like so:

```
$custom_field = get_post_meta($post->ID,'CustomFieldName', true);
```

Comment: yes you are right i already know that i can get it through this function but i want to get it through jqery not php

Comment: you are mixing client- and server- side. You cannot retrieve data from the remote server with JQuery. You have to use a server side language such as PHP. Once you have retrieved the value you can assign it to a JavaScript Variable, and manipulate it, like so: var custom_field = <?php echo $custom_field; ?>;

Comment: @Matanya, you can use JSON to retrieve data from remote server ;)

Comment: @Tom: I suppose you mean retrieving a JSON object with AJAX. Well, this is also done via server-side language, as any other AJAX request. The returned object may be parsed as JSON by json_encode() but that doesn't change the fact that the actual data retrieval happens in the server-side with server-side language

Comment: now i edit my code check it. when i alert the url it gives me undefined. the line echo '<div class="myclass" style="display:none" id="'.$custom_field.'"></div>' doesn't echo the $custom_field when i view the source i get the result <div class="myclass" style="display:none" id=""></div>. here you can see the id is empty i dont know why

Comment: i am unable to figure out that why  $custom_field loose his value

Comment: @Matanya, yes, I misunderstood the retrieve word... I'm not native english speaker, but what I mean was that is possible get the `customField` directly without passing the data to client side ;)

Comment: retriving issue is solve but now there is new issue as i mentioned in my previous comment. i.e $custom_field losse its value in the next line of code which seem very unusal to me

Comment: @KashifWaheed: You are using single quotes incorrectly, try this: `echo '<div class="myclass" style="display:none" id="$custom_field"></div>';`

Comment: i am getting mad that how a verable could loose a value in the next line of code its so..

Comment: @KashifWaheed: I have tested and is working for me... you got the id value empty? Check that the custom field name is *video path*, show me the code on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/)

Comment: yes i get an empty value but only when i pass it to id, above it it give me the value what it have. yes its video path

Comment: 1. $custom_field = get_post_meta($post->ID,'video path', true);?>

2. <div class="myclass" style="display:none" ><?php echo $custom_field;?></div>

3. <?php echo $custom_field; ?>
there are three lines of code in first and last line $custom fields have a value but in middle line it has no value why what could be the possible reason

Comment: @KashifWaheed: You only will see it on the html code, because it has `display:none`

Comment: display none is my need but i can see it in view source and the div is there. but i also tried it without display none mean no style and the result is same

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19832/discussion-between-tom-and-kashif-waheed)

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom attributes prefixed with data-, add this when you retrieve every thumbnail:

```
<img data-video="get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_ulr', true);" src="...">
```

And you can manipulate this "data" using Jquery. For example, to retrieve data in your example use this:

```
var url = $('this').data('video');
```

take a look at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for more info/examples.

Comment: @KashifWaheed: You are using quotes incorrectly: try this: `echo '<div class="myclass" style="display:none" id="$custom_field"></div>';`

Comment: @KashifWaheed: If you still get an empty string, try using var_dump($custom_field) to get the value returned by the function (should be "bool false" if no such field exists)

Comment: @Matanya i did it as what you said result is ok it exsist and the i save the result in a vari able $custom_field and try to use it in next line of code but the varible get empty in the next line of code

Comment: @KashifWaheed, then you are not printing the line correctly (delete single quotes and dots inside that line)